# Error starting JBOSS 7.0.0.0 Final - Services with missing/unavailable dependencies

Tags: jpa, ejb, jboss7.x, hsqldb, persistence.xml

I am having problems while starting a sample app on JBoss server 7.0. 
Below follow piece of start log:

> 12:19:10,156 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss AS 7.0.0.Final "Lightning" started (with errors) in 16391ms - Started 207 of 331 services (67 services failed or missing dependencies, 57 services are passive or on-demand)
>   12:19:10,361 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployment of "crm.war" was rolled back with failure message {"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"crm.war\".jndiDependencyService missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ClienteDAOBean/emf\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ContatoDAOBean/emf\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"crm.war\".component.br/com/crm/model/dao/ContatoDAORemote.START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ContatoDAOBean/emf\" ]","jboss.persistenceunit.\"crm.war#crmUnity\" missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc/CRMDS ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"crm.war\".component.br/com/crm/model/dao/ClienteRemoteDAO.START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ClienteDAOBean/emf\" ]"]}
>   12:19:10,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Stopped deployment crm.war in 82ms
>   12:19:10,445 ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"crm.war\".jndiDependencyService missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ClienteDAOBean/emf\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ContatoDAOBean/emf\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"crm.war\".component.br/com/crm/model/dao/ContatoDAORemote.START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ContatoDAOBean/emf\" ]","jboss.persistenceunit.\"crm.war#crmUnity\" missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc/CRMDS ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"crm.war\".component.br/com/crm/model/dao/ClienteRemoteDAO.START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ClienteDAOBean/emf\" ]"]}}}

crm-ds.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <datasources>
        <local-tx-datasource>
           <jndi-name>CRMDS</jndi-name>
           <connection-url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:database/crm</connection-url>
           <driver>hsqldb.jar</driver>
           <user-name>SA</user-name>
           <password></password>
        </local-tx-datasource>
  </datasources>
```

persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="crmUnity" transaction-type="JTA">
              <jta-data-source>java:/CRMDS</jta-data-source>
              <class>br.com.crm.model.entities.Cliente</class>
              <class>br.com.crm.model.entities.Contato</class>
              <properties>
                     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
                     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
                     <property name="hibernate.showSql" value="true"/>
              </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

The main error is:

> ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"crm.war\".component.br/com/crm/model/dao/ClienteRemoteDAO.START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ClienteDAOBean/emf\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"crm.war\".component.br/com/crm/model/dao/ContatoDAORemote.START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ContatoDAOBean/emf\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"crm.war\".jndiDependencyService missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ContatoDAOBean/emf\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ClienteDAOBean/emf\" ]","jboss.persistenceunit.\"crm.war#crmUnity\" missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.java:CRMDS ]"]}}}

Thank you in advance for help me.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears to be the entity manager missing the datasource. Make sure the JNDI name in both the persistence.xml and -ds.xml is the same (e.g. they should both be java:/CRMDS).

Also JBoss AS 7.0.0 is extremely outdated, if you are starting a new project you should use something newer (either Wildfly or JBoss EAP).

Comment: The jndi names are same in crm-ds.xml and persistence.xml. Running on EAP 6.1 also with error: status JBAS014775 service: missing / does not satisfy  none of the dependencies:
service jboss.naming.context.java.CRMDS (missing) dependent: [ jboss.persistenceunit service "crm.war # crmUnity"] @Stuart Douglas